# Does Photoshop have a file navigator (thumbnail) strip of open images?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm thinking here of the kind of strip that Elements has, showing the open photos at the bottom or side of the display. Very useful if you have too many images open to display in a grid, and you want a quick selector list of thumbnails to see them all and move between them.

If it has one, I can't find it.

If not, how do people handle moving between images when you have several open? Surely not just the tabs? Extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adobe Lightroom or Bridge are typically used for this purpose. Another option is to place your photos in a Library. This will allow you to access your photo assets in various Adobe applications.